# Bone Armature does not work

Tags: bones

I have some issues while adding bones to my figure. Although all parts of the figure are joined together, some parts of the head just stay in the old position while I rotate the head bone. Moreover I don’t get how to connect the bones of the arm in a sensful way to the rest of the armature ?
Thanks for answers 
Jonas :D

[image]

Comment: You really should spend some time documenting yourself. It's clear that you're not familiar with the basics of rigging or skinning. It's very complicated to help you in these conditions, and not very instructive. Moreover, there are many similar topics everywhere, as well as good tutorials.

Some tips for your route: find out about weight painting, and avoid segmenting your rig into several objects when there is no need for it.

Comment: alright thanks for the tipp , yeah I really skipped some of the basics and just experiment a bit